# grunt-responsive-images is giving only one output

Tags: gruntjs

I'm not getting output for 640 and 1024. Can anyone point out the problem in my code

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
responsive_images: {
myTask: {
  options: {
    sizes: [{
      width: 320

    },{
      width: 640

    },{
      width: 1024

    }]
  },
  files: [{
    expand: true,
    src: ['*.jpg'],
    cwd: 'original images/' ,
    custom_dest: 'Responsive Images/'
      }]
    }
  },
});

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-responsive-images');
     grunt.registerTask('default',['responsive_images']);

  };
```

When I run "grunt" I get this
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2rNy.png) . I can't figure it out what wrong I've typed. No error is shown. But still I'm getting only one width i.e "320".

Answer (score 1):

Well I found the solution itself. It should be "dest" instead of "cust_dest".